# Error 001530 : Input Table exceeds the 256 column limit of the .xls file format

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, export, excel

I am unable to export the table using "Conversion tool : table to excel". It shows error

"Error 001530 : Input table exceeds the 256 columnlimit of the .xls file format"

I tried all solutions but no help.

Comment: It sounds like an Excel limit for column width, see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3 . Excel cells must contain strings less than 255 characters with a null terminator. What is your goal here? Excel just isn't going to work, perhaps if you can reveal more of your workflow we could suggest alternative workflows.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I want to perform join operation between a layer with geospatial data and a table. The output of that join operation is a table that I need to export in excel format. Is there a way I can know which value is causing this error?

Comment: You will need to truncate your string fields. Are you sure you *need* excel? Microsoft (JET) Access databases can store a HUGE amount of data in a cell https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-Memo-field-to-store-large-amounts-of-information-70d60485-e4ba-4583-bb67-c2bb6283535a . A good workflow would be to join and export to personal geodatabase then use Microsoft Access to export to excel which should truncate the fields for you; if you want to do this automatically you will need to script in python or ArcObjects.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson:  The error is that number of column in database while exporting was more then 256 due to which this error is coming. I have checked and there is no such excel char limit for one column as you have mentioned in your response.

Comment: If you want to trim down your fields use a field mapping object http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z00000014000000 to hide some fields *before* trying to export.

Comment: The error message doesn't mention character limits, it says column limit. @aditya, how many columns are in the Excel worksheet you are trying to access? If the answer is greater than 256, there's your answer.

Answer (score 3):

> 001530: Input table exceeds the 256 columns limit of the .xls file format

**This error is quite clear**.  You are trying to export to Excel a table that has more than 256 **columns**.  Excel `.xls` format can only take a maximum of 256 columns (fields).

> 001530: Input table exceeds the 256 columns limit of the .xls file
>   format.
>
> **Description**
>
> The Microsoft Excel 97–2003 Workbook (.xls) format has a limit of 256
>   columns.
>
> **Solution**
>
> If not all fields are necessary, a subset of fields can be made
>   unavailable in an intermediate table view or feature layer by using
>   the Field Info control's visible property in the Make Table View or
>   Make Feature Layer tools.

From [Error 001530 Help page](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-01526-01550-001530.htm)

Alternatively, export to a different table format that doesn't have this limitation.